# How can I make an iPad launch an app when device is idle?

Tags: ios, kiosk-mode

I'd like to setup an iPad for use in my kitchen. I would like it to switch to a specific app (or a web page_ when the tablet is idle for some amount of time. Users should be able to launch different apps, and use the iPad 'normally', but when the device becomes idle for some amount of time, I want it to return to a "home" app (or web page).

From what I've read about Guided Access, it doesn't seem like the right solution.

One thought that occurred to me would be to make the home app a "VoIP" app, and arrange to periodically send it fake incoming call push notifications, which should cause iOS to launch/foreground the app if it's not already. I'm not unwilling to do something like that, but obviously that then requires some outboard system to send those notifications.

I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a better/simpler way.

Comment: Even if you used a voice-calling app all you could do is get the calling screen to appear, but it wouldn't actually launch the app into the foreground without user interaction. AFAIK it's not possible, but I'm curious to see if someone has a solution!

Comment: There is no way to programmatically force the app to the foreground. With background modes you can have the app perform some tasks in the background, but that's it.